# Cannot set Fullcalendar background event color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I cannot set the backround color for Fullcalendar (version 2.3.2) events.
I have tried with dayRender, color, backgroundColor without success.
What could be the problem?
Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    width: 750,
    height: 550,
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    year: 2015,
    month: 6,
    date: 13,
    events: [{
        title: 'test',
        stato: 'NoResponseReceived',
        subject: 'test ',
        body: '',
        location: '',
        startdate: '14/7/2015 08:00:00',
        enddate: '14/7/2015 08:30:00',
        start: new Date(2015, 6, 14),
        end: new Date(2015, 6, 14),
        backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
    }],
    color: '#ff0000',
    dayRender: function(calEvent, cell, date) {
        cell.css('background-color', '#ff0000');
    },
    viewRender: function(view, element) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually my problem was that I had included fullcalendar.print.css.

Background events in the file are set as !important and that overrided
whatever I put in my code.